# The sum of all divisors of $N$ is a 2 potency iff $N$ is a product of different Mersenne primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures, divisor-sum, mersenne-numbers

As far as I have controlled:

$\sigma(a)=2^n$, for some $n\in\mathbb N \iff $ $a$ is a product of different Mersenne primes.

The $\Leftarrow$-part is an immediate consequence of that $\sigma$ is multiplicative, but the other part seems more complicated, if it is true.

Maybe this is interesting in the view of that it is unknown if there are only a finite number of Mersenne primes or not.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1836974/78967

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for $n$ squarefree:

Assume the lhs is true. Then you can split $a$ up into its primes. By definition you have $\sigma(p)=p+1$ for each, thus $$\sigma(\prod_{i=1}^r p_i)=\prod_{i=1}^r (p_i+1)=2^n$$
Since $2$ is the only prime factor of the right product, every factor is at least of the "Mersenne form" $2^m-1$.
If $m$ is a prime, we're done. If $m=pq$ ($p$ prime, $q$ integer) is computed then consider
$$2^m-1=(2^p-1)(2^{(q-1)p}+2^{(q-2)p} +...+2^{p+1})$$
Repeat the procedure with $2^{n/p}$.

The generalization could come from the fact that $\sigma(p_n\#)=2^n$ where $p_n\#$ is the primorial, which only consists of square free primes.

Comment: I don't think we know that each prime occurs only to the first power.  You need to account for the possibility that $\sigma(p^k)=2^m$ for some prime $p$ with $k>1$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I restricted the scope of my answer to square free numbers.